# Is checking if a variable is equal to a value and then returning that value redundant?

Tags: vb.net

My company has a piece of software written in VB.net, and I've never really used the language before. I encountered the following:

```
If x Is Nothing Then Return Nothing '  x's type should be an instance of a class
  Return x
```

This seems to be doing the equivalent of:

```
if(x == null) //Object.ReferenceEquals() if you want to be more accurate/verbose?
    return null;
return x;
```

This seems very redundant. Is there some reason a person would do this in VB?

Comment: I can't any reason for the `If` statement there.  Simply returning `x` without the check should have the same result, just as it would in C#.  I think that someone is just being overly cautious without actually understand properly what they're doing.

Comment: Is the person that develop this software still working at your company? if no, then perhaps this the reason. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *could* just be accumulated code rot, the thing that happens when you do minimal changes to code to adapt, rather than properly re-engineering.

For example, it may have been, in the past:

```
If x is Nothing Then
    Return 0
End If
Return x
```

perhaps because callers couldn't handle `nothing`.

When they were changed so they *could* handle it, the function was minimally changed.

This is sometimes the approach taken during field bug fixes to minimise change and hence potential for further damage but I would expect at least a comment suggesting the 'full' change be done in the future.

In any case, thy 'why' is largely irrelevant, you can safely remove the `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to make sure this wasn't some sort of VB.net 'gotcha'.